# How can I log what database and/or collection data is being saved to?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Node app set up with Express, Mongoose and MongoDB and as the title says, I am curious if it’s even possible to log where the data is being saved? I’ve tried googling but I haven’t really found anything that answers my question.

The database is hosted on my local machine. No sharding, no extras, just a simple basic database.

This is basically what I want to achieve:

```
SomeScema = new SomeScema();
SomeSchema.value = 123
SomeSchema.save(function(){
  // log where data is saved
  return res.status(200);
}
```

Comment: can you please specify what do you mean by where? is there any sharding there ?

Comment: Like I said in the title. What database and/or collection. No sharding. Just my simple local database. Will update the post

Comment: For the most part, data goes where you tell it to go. It looks like you want to learn about Dependency Injection and the Strategy Pattern to see methods of swapping out this function and giving it some automatic logging ability. Basically you write it yourself, but automated (after setup)

Comment: Alright, I will look into that!

Comment: I'm not sure what is the original idea of this post, do you want to log information about the collection and the data saved??

Comment: What part of where is difficult to understand?

Comment: "I am curious if it’s even possible to log where the data is being saved?"

Comment: Yes? Where means "location", not "information about"